# How to add signup button in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to add signup button below the sign please help me to fix the issue

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, log in to your WordPress dashboard.
Go to the 'Appearance' -> 'Menus'.
In the 'Menu Structure' -> 'Custom Links' tab.
Enter the URL for the signup page in the 'URL' field and the text that you want to use for the button in the 'Link Text' field.
Click the 'Add to Menu' button.
The new signup button will now be added to your menu. You can use the 'Drag and Drop' feature to rearrange the order of the buttons in the menu.

I hope I helped!